# Adding integer value to an array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, addition, mips, mips32

I am new to MIPS and do not understand what is going on here:

Suppose word array A stores 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, in this order. Assume the starting address of A is in $s0. After the following instructions, what will be the values this array?

```
addi $t0, $s0, 32
lw $t1, 0($t0)
sw $t1, 4($t0)

(a) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
(b) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,9  
(c) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8
(d) None of the above.
```

The answer is "c", but I do not understand why. Here is my thought process:

First line of code:

> Since this is an integer array, adding 32 to the address $s0 and giving it to $t0 would mean giving  the address of A[8] to $t0. A[8] because each integer requires 4 bytes, thus adding 0 to $s0 would result in the address of A[0] and adding 4 to $s0 would result in the address of A[1], and so on...

Second line of code:

> 0($t0) is referencing the first element in $t0 (which I have no idea what that is) and loading it to the register $t1.

Third line of code:

> The address of $t1 is stored in memory to the first element of $t0, which is symbolized by 4($t0).

Again, the above is my thought process, which is most likely wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your thought process is right, and that is the reason why answer c) is the correct one.

The first line, `addi $t0, $s0, 32` assigns *$t0 = $s0 + 32*. As **$s0** contains the address of the first element of array A, and knowing that each element of this array occupies 4 bytes, **$t0** will now hold the address of the ninth element of the array A, A[8] (indices starting with 0). So *$t0=address_of(A[8])*

So, the second line, `lw $t1, 0($t0)`, will load word stored at address **$t0+0**, which is A[8], and stores this word in register **$t1**. Therefore, *$t1=8*.

The third line, `sw $t1, 4($t0)`, will store the word contained in **$t1** at address **$t0+4**, which is the address_of(A[9]). Therefore, *A[9]=8*.